# Bartender application can't connect to the DB

Tags: printer, database, barcode

Hi I have installed bartender trial version in one server and I'm trying to create the DB connection with a DB in another server. When I type in DB server IP & credentials I does not display the available DB list to select.
Is this a restriction for trial version or am I missing something here?

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Have you done your basic testing that you can ping/access the DB server from the bartender application server? Is there a firewall on the DB server that you haven't opened the MS SQL server port (default TCP 1433 I believe) to allow the application server inbound? Is the server on the same subnet as the application server? Does it go through a router?

Comment: @Kinnectus hi, yes I did ping and its working fine.

Comment: Further testing? A ping will only work if ICMP is allowed and the server is responding to them. Testing the MS SQL server port is not the same as ping...

Comment: Hi @Kinnectus the problem was with my DB user. Thank you so much for pointing me the correct way.